# Using d3 to import .csv data error: 404: Not Found error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, csv, import, d3.js

EDIT: I've read more about using Rails & D3 and the advice I've heard is use JSON for incoming data and make your life easier. Lesson learned.

Basic Ruby/Rails app, creating a stock chart with d3.  However, I cannot seem to load my dataset (in this case .csv file saved inside the rails app. Console shows this error:

"GET http:// localhost:3000/pages/sp500.csv 404 (Not Found)" (space added)

My code:

```
    d3.csv("sp500.csv", function (data) {

      data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
      d.price = +d.price;
    });
```

Tried saving the sp500.csv in various directories and calling it in variety of ways, but still stuck.  Thanks for help.

Comment: It's been a while since I've looked at Rails but I wonder if it is interpreting this URL on the server side as an invocation of a REST endpoint.  You might have to do something in your routes file to get it to treat it as a static file request.

Answer (score 1):

Can you access the file via browser directly without your app and d3?

Comment: Correction: no, I can't download it without opening the file locally.  If I try to find the file from the URL in the console it shows nothing has been downloaded, can't find it.

Comment: I do not know what is your environment. For example, on my locally running wamp server, if I try to find some cvs file from the URL it will be downloaded and saved to my system.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because your Rails application isn't serving up the file because it doesn't know to do so. I had the same issue recently when designing an app with Node.js. It has been too long since I have used Rails, so I am afraid that I am not able to help out further than that.